# When texture painting, why do the triangles show more?

Tags: texture-painting

[image: Image showing the problem]

I apologise if this has a straight forward solution, however, I've looked for almost an hour, but still cannot find any solution. Whenever I try to directly paint onto the mesh it highlights the surrounding triangles.

Added the blend file: [image]

And to clarify, this happens immediately after opening the texture paint tab, so it is not vertex painting to my knowledge.

When I paint on the 2D image directly, it does not reproduce this effect, only when I paint directly onto the mesh.

Any help is profoundly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: could you please share this part so that we can try?

Comment: Just for clarification, are you texture painting or vertex painting?

Comment: ^ edited post and shared the file.